# How to implement JaxB in between html page & Restful WebResource Method?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

Iam new in  Jax-rs.I have doubt to passing a data from html page into webresource method.In the html page contains fruitid & fruitname.How to convert these two attributes into Java object i.e.,FruitBean.May be we can use jaxb implemenation.But i don't know further steps to implemation in between html page & web resource method.

Please check the below code snippet for fruitbean

```
@XmlRootElement(name="fruitbean")
public class FruitBean {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

And web resource method passing pararmenter as FruitBean object.check the below method.

```
@POST
@Path("loadObject1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void loadObject1(FruitBean bean){
    System.out.println("Fruit ID" + bean.getId() + " Name" + bean.getName());

}
```

Even I already tried to search on this issue.But i can't understand.Please help me.

**Update :-**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Jax-RS Object</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="services/fruitstore/loadObject1" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" Value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post code from html, how do you send request, or use my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Path("loadObject1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void loadObject1(String bean){  
    FruitBean bean = new com.google.gson.Gson().fromJson(bean, FruitBean.class);
    System.out.println("Fruit ID" + bean.getId() + " Name" + bean.getName());

}
```

from servers send POST request with data `JSON.stringify(fruitBean)`
for example send request using jQuery/ajax

```
var fruitBean  
fruitBean.id = 1  
fruitBean.name = 'name' 
$.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'context-path/loadObject1',  
  data : JSON.stringify(fruitBean)
});
```

Comment: is there to use Jaxb instead of Json

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer on your question. But as I have find binding between JaxB bean and HTTP-request is not implemented yet in Jersey RESTful Web services - it has just someone [hack](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/getting+form+data+as+a+populated+javabean) (but without JaxB)

And that is more-or-less advanced related ability in [RESTEasy JAX-RS](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Form)